# Storing a 30KB BLOB in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

My data is 30KB on disk (Serialized object) was size should the binary field in t-sql be?

Is the brackets bit bytes ?

... so is binary(30000) .... 30KB?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `varbinary(max)` data type; the maximum allowed size for `binary` is 8,000 bytes.  Per [the MSDN page on `binary` and `varbinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx):

> `varbinary [ ( n | max) ]`
>
> Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length.

Answer (score 0):

The number after binary() is the number of bytes, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225972(SQL.80).aspx):

> binary [ ( n ) ]
>
> Fixed-length binary data of n bytes. n
>   must be a value from 1 through 8,000.
>   Storage size is n+4 bytes.

Whether 30kb is 30000 or 30720 bytes depends on which [binary prefix system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) your file system is using.